# Arcgis dissolve output has greater area than inputs

Tags: arcgis-desktop, dissolve

I've been using dissolve to successfully merge polygons (which may or may not overlap) representing mining tenements so that I can calculate their total coverage area (using the geodesic area calculator). However, in one case the output of the dissolve has an 11% greater area than the total area of the input polygons.Have attached a picture of the output.

The input data is from multiple shapefiles. I've selected and merged these into one feature class. I've repaired the geometry of the feature class before running the dissolve.

The dissolve output feature is complex with multiple slivers. I thought that these slivers may be the problem. But eliminating some of them made very little difference to the geodesic area calculation.
I'm baffled!

Does anyone gave any suggestions?

[image: dissolved feature]

Comment: Please edit the question to specify the source of your data (e.g., shapefile, fileGDB, enterprise GDB).

Comment: I'd say repair geometry and try again

Comment: This looks a lot like Northern Territory, Australia.  If so, I suggest using GDA_1994_Australia_Albers projection (EPSG: 3577).  You can set your data frame to that projection, and calculate geometry on your area field.

Comment: Many thanks @FelixIP I've done that and it made no difference - have clarified in the question.

Comment: Thanks @Fezter. You're correct. It's all the petroleum leases in the NT. 
I'd been hoping that by calculating geodesic areas I didn't need to use a projected co-ordinate system. However, I've done as you suggested and re-projected. It's pretty interesting:
-The calculated area of the un-dissolved polygons matched the geodesic area.
-The calculated area of the dissolved feature is slightly less than the sum of the un-dissolved polygons and much less than the geodesic area (which is still way too big). 
Must be a problem with the geodesic area calculation and this feature.

Comment: It doesn't solve your problem, but you could run the Erase tool and see exactly where the areas in question are. This may help you troubleshoot what is going wrong with your Dissolve.

Comment: Database settings on DD sets, e.g. precision could cause it

Comment: That the geodetic area is larger is correct as it puts the area on the curved surface of the earth. It looks like you have really large areas. In this case it might be correct the way the programm calculates it than the effect is greater the greater the extent of your data is. And in this case the differences of many small areas might be lower than the effect of one large area. Your extent is above 1000km? Albers is an equal area projection, but it is said to be better in east-west than north-south shaped areas. Would be interesting how large the effect is in other projections.

Comment: run Integrate with a 10 meter tolerance or experiment with different tolerances. Integrate changes the input, so you may want to make a backup first.

Answer (score 1):

Try starting an editing session with your original feature class. Use the Merge tool in the Editor dropdown and combine your features. The area may not update without calculating.  I find the best way is to open your attribute table and go to your area field. Do calculate geometry. The calculation should reflect the new amount.